# Weird things happening with CSS after server change

Tags: css

So I had my ["My Work" page](http://eyesofstyle.com/my-work/) laid out exactly the way I wanted it yesterday, and I needed to change servers. I changed servers, and all my other sites are fine, but the look of my "My Work" page got messed up. Basically the background image from the bottom widget area is now in the middle of the page. It looks like nothing on this page is inside of its container anymore. It definitely was before I changed servers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've no idea why it's only affecting this one page on this one site. I tried re-uploading the css file, and the entire theme to the new server and nothing changed.

Edit: Sorry, here is the css for the widget area that's floating in the middle of the page:

```
.widget-area {
  padding-top: 40px;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color:#d2c1ad;
  margin-top: 3%;
  background-image:url(images/widgetarea.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 101%;
}
```

Comment: I think it would help tremendously if you posted the css that applies to your question.

Comment: Did you try using a browser dev tools/debugger to see if anything's NOT loading? "I changed servers" means you probably missed something.

Comment: It also would be helpful to see a before and after pic so we know whats not looking right. To me everything looks fine...but I don't know what it looked like before.

Comment: Thanks @JakeSmith I added that. Sorry!

Comment: @zazvorniki unfortunately I didn't take a screenshot yesterday. Do you see how the black, wavy image is floating in the middle of the page? That's the problem- it's supposed to be at the bottom where the email sign up, and social icons are.

Comment: try opening up your console, it looks like either a float is not being cleared or a dive was left open. Moe then likely the float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
Floated items do not take up any space. So even though you have a bunch of .gallery-item divs in there, they are not making the container have a height since they're floated. You need to clear the float. The easiest way is to add a div after the last .gallery-item. Give it the css of clear:both;

<s>On line 555 of your stylesheet where you have .widget-area, add:</s>

```
background-position: bottom center;
```

Comment: Thank you @kthornbloom- that does move it to the bottom. I think the main problem though is that none of the containers are containing their elements. If they were, the background image would move to the bottom on its own. It's so weird because I didn't change anything, and this is only happening on this one page. I just can't figure it out!

Comment: looks like you were right about the `float` there :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `margin-top` on your `aside` objects in the widget.  To prove this, change the `margin-top` to a smaller value for your `.widget` class.  For me, this moved the black wiggly thingy to the bottom, just above the footer, and the three `aside` elements were to the right, all above or below each other.

I'm guessing there is a better way to make this work, and I personally would stay away with using percentages.  But I'm in no way a css expert and there are plenty of those on here that might give you a better, more robust solution to your problem.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that and it didn't move the image at all, just adjusted the margin of the widgets.

Comment: keep trying smaller amounts, maybe it is the screen I'm on.  Basically the sharing buttons are being pushed further down than the parent element and because you are using `display: inline-block`, the sharing buttons go to the next "line"

Comment: Fixed! 
I changed the id & class from:

    #gallery-1 .gallery-item {
    float: left;
    }
to

    #gallery-1 .gallery-item {
    float: none;
    }
Thanks to everyone who takes time out of their day to answer questions, it's seriously awesome and I hope someday soon I will be able to return the favor!

Comment: Make sure to give @kthornbloom his credit.  He called the `float` value being the culprit.  Glad you got it though :)

Comment: It appears I can't upvote until I have 15 reputation

Comment: No worries, its the thought that counts :)